# Laravel count how many child elements has every row

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to make an algorith which calculates how many childs has every row. I have a car model which can have multiple exams. I want to get how many cars have one exam and how many cars have multiple exams. The code I show below takes 21s to execute because I have 10k+ rows.

```
$cars = Car::get();
$cars->map(function ($item, $key) use (&$recurrent) {
  if($item->exam->count()==1)
  {
     $recurrent['single']++;
  }
  else
  {
     $recurrent['multiple']++;
  }
});
```

Comment: What does the `$cars` contain exactly? No need to show all 10k rows, just a single one. Laravel collections add a layer of abstraction and thus overhead, you'd be better off using plain arrays for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx. for your answer Mozammil, I have corrected your code, and I post it.

```
$cars = Car::withCount('exam')->get();
$recurrent = array("single" => $cars->where('exam_count', '=', 1)->count(), "multiple" => $cars->where('exam_count', '>', 1)->count());
```

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off by using Eloquent's [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships). For example, assuming you have a relationship `exams` in your Car model.

```
$cars = App\Car::withCount('exams')->get();

foreach ($cars as $car) {
    echo $car->exams_count;
}
```

If you want to get cars having a certain amount of exams or more, you could do this:

```
$cars = App\Car::withCount('exams')->get()
    ->having('exams_count', '>', 5)
    ->get();
```